# Create shadow for dialog

Tags: android-layout, android

I want to create a shadow for my custom dialog is that possible ?

```
GhazalActivity.public void viewShareMenu() {
        Dialog share=new Dialog(this,R.style.shareDialogStyle);
        share.setContentView(R.layout.share_popup_layout);
        LayoutParams params = share.getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.y = this.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.topbar_height);
        params.gravity=(Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.TOP);
        share.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
        share.show();
}
```

styles.xml :

```
<style name="shareDialogStyle" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:fadeEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:fadeDuration">1500</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/temp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">5</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">10</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

share_popup_layout.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:background="@color/bg_Ghazal_share_menu"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        style="@style/shareDialogButtons"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

is there any solution for doing that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259614/android-popupwindow-elevation-does-not-show-shadow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created my own custom dialog with a dropped shadow, you can use it as your desire, in the first step you should create a Android shape for both shadow and dialog frame. Here is what I have supplied (**dialog_frame_shadow.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"> <!-- this shape is used as shadow -->
            <padding android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:top="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#44000000"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"> <!-- this is for dialog frame -->
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            <stroke android:color="#ff272727" android:width="2dp" />
            <gradient android:angle="90"
                android:startColor="#ffa7a7a7"
                android:centerColor="#ff6a6a6a"
                android:endColor="#ffa7a7a7"
                android:type="linear"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

In the next step you should change your dialog theme as what is in the following:

```
 <style name="my_dialog_theme">
     ...
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_frame_shadow</item>
     ...
 </style>
```

Now you are done, just create a new instance of the `Dialog` class and apply this theme to it (in Dialog constructor):

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.my_dialog_theme);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mdialog);
dialog.show();
```

Here is its screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this, create an xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
    android:startColor="#ffffff"
    android:centerColor="#d3d7cf"
    android:endColor="#2e3436"
    android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

make a View and set above xml to its backgroung like:

```
 <View android:id="@+id/divider" android:background="@drawable/black_white_gradient"

    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="5sp"
     <!--greater the height, more wider the shadow-->
   />
```

now if you want to drop shadow to the left of your view, align this view to you views left, if you want shadow on bottom, align this view under you view ...hope you get it now

Comment: I want to make shadow under my view not a background !

Comment: I've tried this but this is my output with your code: http://img.majidonline.com/pic/289367/screenshot-1364990062579.png i want to do this:http://img.majidonline.com/pic/289369/screenshot-13649900625792.png

Comment: also take a look at this  [link](http://blog.donnfelker.com/2011/08/01/android-rounded-corners-with-a-beveldrop-shadow/)